# How to remove blank lines between matches in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to remove blank lines between two lines using Ansible but cannot get it work. My source file looks like this:

```
###This line has blank lines after it



###End of block

#More lines
```

And I would like the result to look like this:

```
###This line has blank lines after it
###End of block

#More lines
```

So far I have this task using the replace module:

```
- name: Remove blank lines between matches
  replace:
    path: /home/vagrant/abcd
    after: '###This line has blank lines after it'
    regexp: '(^\n)'
    replace: ''
    before: '###End of block'
```

But the task does not appear to work. In fact the task does not do anything to the source file.

If I remove the last line of the task (*before: '###End of block'*). The lines do get removed but it also removes all blank lines until EOF which is not what I want. Here is the result with the last line removed:

```
###This line has blank lines after it###End of block
#More lines
```

Which is not expected.

I have a solution using sed but I want to keep it idempotent as possible. Maybe I need better regex?

Any ideas please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After playing with this some more and playing with the regex I've come up with this:

```
- name: Remove blank lines between matches
  replace:
    path: /home/vagrant/abcd
    after: '###This line has blank lines after it'
    regexp: '(^\s*$)'
    replace: ''
```

This produces:

```
###This line has blank lines after it
###End of block

#More lines
```

Which is what I was after. But I will wait until the bug is fixed before using in production.

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31354 using after and before parameters together currently does not work as expected.

You can delete **after** paremeter from your task and in this case it will work as expected, but I know that it is not what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess I will have to wait until it's fixed and use sed for the time being.